# how to display info at extra space above or below the scroll end of UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have see some apps making use of the extra space you find when scrolling further to the top or bottom of `UITableView`.

How can I displayed an `UILabel` in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the frame property of your `UILabel` to be outside the `UITableView` like this:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, -40, 320, 40);
```

...and make sure that the `clipsToBounds` property of your table view is set to `NO`.